# Error handling in controller (MVC structure)

Tags: php

Lately, I'm using domain model pattern, and my controllers methods often looks like (yii2 example, verify user in loyalty system with Ajax response).

```
if (LoyaltyDomModel::loyaltyVerification($post_data)) {

    if (LoyaltyDomModel::setVerify(Yii::$app->user->identity, $post_data)) {

        return  ['body'=>'successfull','status' => true];
    }
    else {
        return  ['body'=>'unable update user','status' => 'error'];
    }
}
else {
    return  ['body'=>'errorcardno','status' => 'error'];
}
```

If logic is more complex I have a lot of `if` statement with model methods which return bool values, for example (I'm trying to decouple models logic in atomic methods), and it looks like not healthy. Should I encapsulate logic of return errors in models? What is best practices?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. "Too many if statements" is one of our most common inappropriate question titles. Our convention is to state what the code accomplishes, and show the code in context — preferably your entire function, for something like this. See [ask].

Comment: ok, I'm edit my question

Comment: IMO, I'd push those if statements into a trait class and call them individualistically during the controllers execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I advice you forego `if` checks completely and go for `try-catch` blocks, and have your verifiers throw exceptions on error. So, you do something like this:

```
try {
     LoyaltyDomModel::loyaltyVerification($post_data);
     LoyaltyDomModel::setVerify(Yii::$app->user->identity, $post_data);

     return  ['body'=>'successfull','status' => true];
} catch (LoyaltyVerificationException $e) {
     return ['body' => $e->getMessage(), 'status' => 'error']
} catch (UserUpdateException $e) {
     return ['body' => $e->getMessage(), 'fields' => $e->getFields(), /* you can pass custom info to exceptions, right? */, 'status' => 'error'];
}
```

Also, it's not a good idea to return `bool` in one case (`'status' = true`) and string in another (`'status' = 'error'`);

Comment: A generally good suggestion, but I would be somewhat concerned about mixing expected application events and code paths (like a user verification process failure, input data validation, login verification, etc.) with those that truly represent some unexpected **exception**al state in your application (like failing to get a database connection). In this case it is unclear from OP whether these `else` conditions truly represent application state failures or validation-type failures which would be expected in normal application execution.